# Examples of the single dot form of Optional?

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, optional-arguments

I've known of the single dot form of Optional for a while, but never had occasion to actually use it:

[image]

Are there any good examples of use cases for it other than in relation to `Default`?

Comment: Searching for `Default Optional` turns up 105 questions and answers, some of which may be relevant.

Comment: @bbgodfrey most of those which speak of : not .

Comment: `x+x^2 /. x^n_. :> n` - this is probably quite common usage. Yet tough to find `_.` by search engine :-/

Comment: Two more examples: `{2 x, a x, x} /. n_. x :> n` & `{2 + x, a + x, x} /. n_. + x :> n`.

Comment: Wolfram Language Tutorial: [Optional and Default Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html)